# Сохранить объект File

Tags: java, android, io

Есть загрузчик данных с HTTP, на выходе он выдает объект типа `File`, как мне его сохранить в папку с приложением?

Везде искал, в примерах только записывали данные типа `String`, других примеров не нашел.

Подозреваю, что, возможно, это как-то реализуется с помощью `ObjectOutput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записать объект класса `File` на диск (в данном случае в internal storage) можно с помощью файловых потоков:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToSave);
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(getFilesDir(), "fileToSave.ext"));
byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) fileToSave.length()];
fileInputStream.read(fileContent);
fileInputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.write(fileContent);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Здесь `fileToSave` – объект класса `File`, который требуется сохранить в internal storage, `"fileToSave.ext"` – имя сохраненного файла.

В вышеприведенном коде происходит получение `FileInputStream` по исходному `File`, далее его содержимое считывается в `byte[]` и этот массив байтов записывается в `FileOutputStream`.